# ColdFusion Builder debugger - Expressions - "The variable is not defined" bug. Is there a patch/solution?

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

When I use ColdFusion Builder debugger and I try to look up the value of a variable in the "Expressions" window CFB is telling me that

> The variable is undefined.

when it is clearly not the case. Look at this screenshot:

[image]

Variable `a` is defined perfectly fine. Clearly this is a bug in CFB. It is drastically slowing down my work.

**Is there a known patch/fix/workaround/magic spell for this bug?**

Comment: Visibly, you've set two variables. But elsewhere, it's trying to evaluate something that's looking for `a`. It's at that point that `The variable is undefined`. It might not be `a` that's undefined. Can you show more of the code?

Comment: "elsewhere" is the "expressions" window. Whatever is available in scope, in memory is available in "expressions" window. Code around this example is proprietary, I cannot post it. Even if I would I don't see how that could help.